# why the controller not working in angiular js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, jstree

I am trying to implement jstree in angular .I used this plugin
https://github.com/ezraroi/ngJsTree
I am getting this error

**b.tree.jstree is not a function**

I follow all steps and make a codepen but my tree is not display .

here is my code
http://codepen.io/naveennsit/pen/qbRyVP?editors=101

```
angular.module('app',['ngJsTree']).controller('myCtrl',function($scope,$log){ 
      $scope.treeConfig = {
        core : {
            multiple : false,
            animation: true,
            error : function(error) {
                $log.error('treeCtrl: error from js tree - ' + angular.toJson(error));
            },
            check_callback : true,
            worker : true
        },
        types : {
            default : {
                icon : 'glyphicon glyphicon-flash'
            },
            star : {
                icon : 'glyphicon glyphicon-star'
            },
            cloud : {
                icon : 'glyphicon glyphicon-cloud'
            }
        },
        version : 1,
        plugins : ['types','checkbox']
    };



     $scope.originalData = [
        { id : 'ajson1', parent : '#', text : 'Simple root node', state: { opened: true} },
        { id : 'ajson2', parent : '#', text : 'Root node 2', state: { opened: true} },
        { id : 'ajson3', parent : 'ajson2', text : 'Child 1', state: { opened: true} },
        { id : 'ajson4', parent : 'ajson2', text : 'Child 2' , state: { opened: true}}
    ];
    $scope.treeData = [];
    angular.copy($scope.originalData,$scope.treeData);


})
```

any update ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your settings, you include angular js first then jquery, but seem like jstree expects angular to use full version of jquery instead of jquery lite

Reversing the order of angular and jquery library include in setting works:

```
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.min.js
```

Updated codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OMWoYW?editors=101